# How to redirect someone when they click a option in a form list and show them the answer from what they chose

Tags: html

I just started a couple weeks ago and I don't know js/html that much, I don't know how to redirect showing the answer from the list:

```
<html>
  <body>
 <form>
  <input list="questions" name="questions">
  <datalist id="questions">
    <option id="1" value="How far is the moon?">
    <option id="2" value="whats 9x2">
    <option id="3" value="what is a corkscrew?">
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit"> <!--this is the part where
i am struggling on. i dont know how to show the answer from
id when they click submit-->

</form>

    <script>
    document.getElementById(1) = "238,900 mi";
    </script>
  <body>  
 <html>
```

Comment: A little confused about your question. Do you want it so that once the submit button is clicked it tells you the answer to whichever question you selected?

Comment: Yes, exactly what u said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I defined an array of answers, where each index in the array is according to it's question index (first answer for the first question and so on).

Then I'm scanning the entire options (`datalist`), looking for option that have the same value as of the input field.

When I find it, I just set the value of the input field (`listObj`) to the corresponding answer from the `answers` array, and that's all.

I hope it helps you.

```js
let answers = ["238,900 mi", "18", "whatever"];

function submitFunction() {
  var listObj = document.getElementById('questions_list');
  var datalist = document.getElementById(listObj.getAttribute("list"));

  for (var i = 0; i < datalist.options.length; i++) {
    if (datalist.options[i].value == listObj.value) {
      listObj.value = answers[i];
      break;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form onsubmit="return submitFunction()">
    <input list="questions" id="questions_list" name="questions">
    <datalist id="questions">
    <option id="0" value="How far is the moon?">
    <option id="1" value="whats 9x2">
    <option id="2" value="what is a corkscrew?">
  </datalist>

    <input type="submit">
    <!--this is the part where
i am struggling on. i dont know how to show the answer from
id when they click submit-->
  </form>


  <body>
    <html>
```

Comment: Is there another way instead of adding answers in order from id?

Comment: @Arxzl yes. You can create a dictionary between question to answer.